# C# - ASP.NET MVC Get data from form to controller, I get an empty object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

i can't seem to find the answer online...

I have a form where people can add persons. However the person I receive from the post request is empty.

My personModel has a few properties , Naam, Leeftijd and Hobbie.

My Create view has a form made with @Html.LabelFor.

Model:

```
public class PersoonModel
{
    public string Naam { get; private set; }
    public int Leeftijd { get; private set; }

    public string Hobbie { get; private set; }

    public PersoonModel(string naam,int leeftijd, string hobbie )
    {
        Naam = naam;
        Leeftijd = leeftijd;
        Hobbie = hobbie;
    }

    public PersoonModel()
    {

    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Dashboard",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Persoon</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Naam)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Naam)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Leeftijd)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Leeftijd)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hobbie)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hobbie)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create new Person"/>
  </fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PersoonModel persoonModel = new PersoonModel();
        return View(persoonModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PersoonModel Persoon)
    {
        personen.Add(Persoon);
        return Redirect("/Dashboard");
    }
```

I can't seem to get the layout good on stackoverflow, but I hope you understand it
The persoonmodel Persoon(in my Controller) is empty

Comment: can you please also show your `<form>` tag (or `BeginForm` command, whichever you use)?

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Dashboard",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
This is how I start creating my form

Comment: Please add extra code to your actual question, in the right place in the code, so it's in context and can be properly formatted - thanks. (P.S. To do that, click the "edit" button just under the little blue "c#" tag)

Comment: I tried my best, but stackoverflow keeps giving me this message : Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Ok. So did you do that? You seem to have placed it as a quotation (`>`  mark at the start of the line) rather than code. But you do seem to have managed to include it, at least.

Comment: Just like the others suggested, please share your form.

Comment: That is my form

Comment: Have you applied model binding in your view?

Comment: @SafiUllah what do you mean? You can clearly see the code is generating textboxes using HTML Helpers which should produce the correct form elements. What other info are you asking OP to provide, exactly? The form looks ok to me, it's unclear what the issue is, really.

Comment: Yes I have, It is this line of code, Right?
@model DisplayData.Models.PersoonModel

Comment: @TheProgrammer The next thing to do is to see what your form is actually doing. Load your page. Then open your browser's Developer Tools. I'd suggest using Chrome's tools if you can. Go to the Network tab. Tick the "preserve log" option (in Chrome, the option may be called something else in other browsers). Now put some data in your form and submit it. A new line should appear in the network tab showing the HTTP request your postback generated. You should check that it's going to the right URL, and that the Body / Form Data section of the request contains the form data you typed.

Comment: If you're unsure what it's telling you, add a screenshot of the tools. I can't see any obvious reason why it wouldn't bind your values on postback, so we need to check that the code is really doing what it looks like it should do. (P.S. Checking your network tools is a really useful debugging technique in general with web apps)

Comment: I just did what you said, And I see that it's going to the right URL :Dashboard/Create (I think this is the url it should redirect to?)
Also the Form Data is the same from the data I put in.

Comment: When you say "empty" what do you mean? You've debugged and the POST/Create method is invoked and the `Persoon` param is null?

Comment: Yes they are null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your setters are private and MVC model binder cannot fill-in the private values:

```
public class PersoonModel
{
    // remove private before set
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int Leeftijd { get; set; }
    public string Hobbie { get; set; }

    // more code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But you do not want the properties to be public set right? That's what people told me

Comment: Well, if you keep them private, then MVC model binder won't have access to bind your model... in my opinion, you need to ask those people to justify their argument with a reason :-) It is perfectly fine (and very common) to use public setters for your model properties.

Comment: Ah oki, it's the teachers who told me that, but that was when we were working in Windows forms application :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using all that code in your model.
I also took the liberty to change the variables to english.

Just use this

The Model

```
public class PersonModel
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public int PID { get; set; }
public string Hobbie { get; set; }
}
```

The View

```
// path to your personModel
@ApplicationName.ModelFolder.PersonModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Dashboard",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<fieldset>
<legend>Person</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PID)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hobbie)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hobbie)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Create new Person"/>
</fieldset>
}
```

and the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    PersonModel personModel = new PersonModel();
    return View(personModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PersonModel model)
{
    personen.Add(model);
    return Redirect("/Dashboard");
}
```

This should get the values on the post function if you debug it.

Comment: You mean the constructor code in the Model? That's so I could set the properties private set instead of public. So I can set the properties once in the constructor

Comment: You don't need to do this explicitly in MVC. Framework does this for you.
In your post function values will get set in the model automatically.

Comment: Oke , I did not know that :)